# How to make android program compatible with all versions

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem in running my app on different android versions. Actually, my application is running on versions up to 4.3 but not on the versions released after that. I want my application to run on the versions up to 5.0. I need help to achieve my desired goal. Can anyone here help me out?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hurryapppointalert_client"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


<activity 
    android:name="com.example.hurryapppointalert_client.CreateAccount"
    android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

<activity 
    android:name="com.example.hurryapppointalert_client.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.hurryapppointalert_client.LoginPage"
    android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>


        <receiver android:name=".TextMessageReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551): Process: com.example.hurryapppointsalert_point, PID: 29551
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid message body
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:287)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at com.example.hurryapppointsalert_point.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
08-30 08:57:34.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: Why won't your app run on later version? What's the problem?

Comment: I dont know. that's why i've posted this manifest file here I'm not getting this that why this is happening when i've specified the targetversion to 22.

Comment: is there any other way to do that? may be i'm doing in a wrong way ? plz tell me if yu find any mistake in my manifest file

Comment: What sort of crashes do you get on > 4.3?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by it not working. Does it not install? Does it crash when it runs? (If so, please post the logcat output.) Something else?

Comment: i've installed the app on 5.0 thn it crash wen moving to second activity but thisis not happening wen i'm running the same app on 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The `<uses-sdk>` tag is relevant here. In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for that tag you can see that the way you've configured it does not prevent your app from being installed on your desired target.

If you want to be compatible with ALL versions of Android you can simply remove `android:minSdkVersion` and it will default to version 1. If you also do not set `android:maxSdkVersion` you effectively allow your app to be installed on all versions of Android.

That said, and given your AndroidManifest, I'd reckon the problem is not in your AndroidManifest at all.

Comment: but i've not specified maxSdkVersion then why it is crashing again and again on android versions released after 4.3?

Comment: @RabiaIftikhar use adb logcat to discover the true reason behind the crash. Filtering by "System.err" usually helps in this situation.